# Code to make batch file check HDD space and only run if 30gb or more is available

Tags: cmd, storage, backup

I have a script that I use for backing up.

Currently it does not error if there isn't enough space and reports everything was fine.

Is there a way I can add a storage check at the start and only allow it to run if over 30gb is free.
Then error if not.

I'd rather use cmd than powershell

Answer (score 0):

Use "`fsutil volume diskfree c:`" to get size left on drive, make it a variable using "`set`" and compare it to 30

EDIT:
Alternative is "`dir|find "bytes free"`"